# Tableau Time Series Prediction using Python Integration

Tags: tableau-api, tabpy

I need help regarding the time series in Tableau. So far Here is what I can do.

- Connect to TabPY
- Call / Run scripts on TabPy

My current issue is that tableau doesn't seem to allow more output than input elements. Say I want to use the last 100 data points to predict the coming 10 points. Input of the data to python isn't a problem. The problem comes when I want to return a list with 110 elements. I've also tried returning the 10 elements and it complaints that it expects 100 elements list.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Share your TabPy code so the users can take a look at it. It's hard to solve an issue without replicating/seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work around. You can see the post [here](https://www.clearpeaks.com/tableau-python/) for more information. Basically you shift the original values by the prediction amount and then have the prediction return the same amount as the shifted original